# Upload file with webrequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

Im trying to upload an image to an imagehost  `http://uploads.im/`.

According to its very short API `http://uploads.im/apidocs` this is a way of doing that:

```
http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png
```

Note that in this example he is upploading an image from the internet and Im trying to upload a file from my computer.

Code:

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
{
    //Converts the image i want to upload to a bytearray
    Image postData = img;
    byte[] byteArray = imageToByteArray(postData);                

    //Is this adress not correct maybe? Is there a way to test?
    WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create("http://uploads.im/api?upload=");
    wrq.Method = ("POST");

    //Im thinking that here I need som code
    //that specifys the file i want to upload (bytearray)

    using (WebResponse wrs = wrq.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = wrs.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        tempJson = json;
    }
}
```

Please have look! Thanks!

EDIT, new code:

```
string filepath = @"c:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Bilder\images\blank.gif";

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadFile("http://uploads.im/api?upload", filepath);
}
```

I get the error:  : The underlying connection closed

EDIT with try catch:

```
string filepath = @"c:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\sack.png";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.UploadFile("http://uploads.im/api?upload", filepath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the exception message (e.Message).

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Comment: What I meant was to wrap the `client.UploadFile` bit with try/catch and show the message there.

Comment: Hang on and i´ll see if I can figure out how to do that

Comment: added a new edit..is that the right way to try/catch?
The catch contains the same info as earlier..I.e Underlying connection closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void UploadImage(string filepath)
{

    using(WebClient uploader = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            uploader.UploadFile(new Uri("http://uploads.im/api?upload"), filepath);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured :(\r\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using *http://uploads.im/api?upload* as the Endpoint, because, as read in the docs, it will be treated as `REQUEST` and will automatically detect the upload of an image.
However, I tried this code myself and get disconnected every-time without any meaningful response, just `The remote host unexpectedly closed the connection`. According to the docs you should get a `Bad request` when something is wrong. I contacted the support and hope they can tell me more about it. *(Edit: They did not)*

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems like a more effective solution than what i have now..I still get an error thogh..please see Edit

Comment: I should also add that Im doing this in order to receive a response from ther uploads.im containing a href for the image...

Comment: You can read the response from the Webclient. If you really just need to get the url of the pic adding __format=text__ should save work for parsing XML/JSON because you get only the URL as plain text then. I think you really should read the documentation again. And you're not handling the exception right. What you're doing right now is catching the exception and throwing it as a new one. I will add some more code with explanation when I'm home, but I would suggest that you read the documentation of the API and the Webclient class on MSDN again.

Comment: By the way: How big is the picture you're trying to upload? Did you tried different with different sizes?

Comment: Thank you, I have read the API and tried to use the format=text-option in order to only receive the url..That was when I used the code in my first question, it returned null. However, when i used for,at=xml it worked..The images I have tried to post have all been very small, like 100kb...Lookong forward to your code when you get home! Thanks!